# Shouldn't this be in a library somewhere?

Tags: haskell

I was writing some code to generate a lot of random values and add them to a structure, and I needed a mechanism to chain up identical IO actions. So, I wrote this:

```
chain :: Monad m => Int -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
chain 0 _ a = return a
chain n f a = f =<< chain (n-1) f a
```

I get a suspicion that this should be in some library somewhere, but I couldn't find it in Control.Monad. Is this function already written? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it exists somewhere, but it can be neatly defined as:

```
chain :: Monad m => Int -> (c -> m c) -> c -> m c
chain n = foldr (>=>) return . replicate n
```

[*monad-loops*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-loops-0.4.3/docs/Control-Monad-Loops.html) has a few potentially useful functions in that vein (`foldr (>=>) return`, for instance, is `concatM`), though not exactly your `chain`.

Comment: Thank you for the simple improvement to my construction.

Answer (score 6):

If I were to propose a library to put it in, I'd propose adding `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instances for the following newtype:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
import Control.Monad
import GHC.Prim (coerce)

newtype KleisliEndo m a = KE { runKE :: a -> m a }
instance Monad m => Monoid (KleisliEndo m a) where
    mempty = coerce (return @m @a)
    mappend = coerce ((>=>) @m @a @a @a)
```

Then [`stimesMonoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#v:stimesMonoid) is your operation.

I wouldn't be surprised to learn that this newtype is indeed in a library somewhere, too.

Comment: just a note - `TypeApplication` is a very recent addition to GHC (8.0) see https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication for more details

Answer (score 6):

The answer proposed by @duplode (involving `foldr`) is of course correct. However, it is slightly annoying that one must choose between `foldl` and `foldr` here, since really `(>=>)` is really associative. In fact, this is just *begging* to be solved using [`fold :: Monoid m => t m -> m`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:fold).

Unfortunately, there is no `newtype` wrapper for this monoid in `Data.Monoid`. The closest one gets is [`Endo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) which falls a bit short. However with [`Endomorphism`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.4.2/docs/Data-Monoid-Endomorphism.html#) from the [`monoid-extras`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras) package we can generate the useful `composeN` function @jpath suggests for your function generalized to `Category`:

```
composeN :: Category cat => Int -> cat a a -> cat a a
composeN n = getEndomorphism . foldMap Endomorphism . replicate n
```

Then what we really want is to use `composeN` for the [`Kleisli`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:Kleisli) category

```
chain :: Monad m => Int -> (c -> m c) -> c -> m c
chain n = runKleisli . composeN n . Kleisli
```

#### EDIT

Following @Daniel Wagners answer - `Endomorphism` is the monoid you need. I think this is as nice as it can get:

```
import Data.Monoid.Endomorphism (Endomorphism(..))
import Data.Semigroup (stimesMonoid)
import Control.Arrow (Kleisli(..))

chain :: Monad m => Int -> (c -> m c) -> c -> m c
chain n = (runKleisli . getEndomorphism) . stimesMonoid n . (Endomorphism . Kleisli)
```

If you are not averse to enabling language extensions, you can use actually get rid of the `runKleisli . getEndomorphism` and `Endomorphism . Kleisli` with coercions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Monoid.Endomorphism (Endomorphism(..))
import Data.Semigroup (stimesMonoid)
import Control.Arrow (Kleisli(..))
import Data.Coerce (coerce)

chain :: forall m c. Monad m => Int -> (c -> m c) -> c -> m c
chain = coerce (stimesMonoid @Int @(Endomorphism (Kleisli m) c))
```

Comment: May I propose using `foldMap` instead of `fold . map`.

Comment: In your edit you forgot to conjugate with the kleisli newtype.

Comment: @jpath Thanks! I completely missed that. I was already making a `composeN` when you answered but I hadn't generalized the signature. Nice idea!

Comment: Also I think you still have to import `Kleisli(..)` and `runKleisli` from `Control.Arrow`.

Comment: @Alec Nice, I didn't know about `Endomorphism`! Some (like me) might also like the spelling that turns on `ScopedTypeVariables` and then has `chain = coerce (stimesMonoid @Int @(Endomorphism (Kleisli m) c))`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Oh I see the trick you are playing! I like it very much indeed!!! I will add it on to my answer.

Comment: Also maybe you should point out that `Data.Monoid.Endomorphism` is from the `monoid-extras` package.

Comment: This is all completely out of my depth. I can't see myself importing endomorphism and semigroup for a function this simple.

Comment: @ChristianOudard I probably wouldn't either, although mostly because I would have to bring in an external dependency. However, should `Endomorphism` be moved into `Data.Monoid`, I would reconsider - the abstractions make the intent clearer, there is no extra cost (definitely not for the `coerce` version), and `stimesMonoid` may actually be a bit more efficient (it uses a halving technique) than the solution with `replicate`.

Answer (score 3):

For such cases it is always a good idea to search for your desired type on Stackage, Hoogle **and** Hayoo. In this case you can find [two results](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=Int+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+a%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+m+a) on Hayoo and [some more](https://www.stackage.org/lts-7.12/hoogle?q=Monad+m+%3D%3E+Int+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+m+a%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+m+a) on Stackage. However in this case I think I would just use @duplode's solution instead of depending on another package for that (unless you like a lot of the functions in one of the packages).

Another tip if you do search on those sites is to think of possible generalisations of your function. For example in this case if one was willing to conjugate with a `Kleisli` newtype wrapper a function like this would also work:

```
 composeN :: Category cat => Int -> cat a a -> cat a a
```

Sadly I couldn't find such a function.

(`Categorie`s are things that can be composed and have an identity.)