# Composing arbitrarily many maps in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How is it possible to compose n maps in Haskell?
I've tried doing it recursively:

```
composeMap 0 f = (\x -> x)
composeMap n f = (.) f (composeMap (n-1) f)
```

And iteratively:

```
composeMap' n k f g =
  if n == k then g
            else composeMap' n (k+1) f (f . g)

composeMap n f = composeMap' n 0 f (\x -> x)
```

But to no avail. Haskell thinks I am constructing an infinite type.
This is obviously false as the function defined is finite for any
n >= 0.

Any suggestions?

Some have posted solutions treating f as having the following type signature:

```
f :: a -> a
```

However, I want this to work for f s.t. f is polymorphic in the following way:

```
f :: a -> a'
f :: a' -> a''
```

In particular, I want a function that works for the function map, with possible type signatures:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map (polymorphic) :: ([a] -> [b]) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]
```

The function compiles perfectly fine, but Haskell infers the following type signature, which is not what I want:

```
composeMap'' :: Int -> (b -> b) -> b -> b
```

I've even tried wrapping map in a monad, but Haskell still thinks I'm constructing an infinite type:

```
composeMap n f = foldl (>>=) f (replicate n (\x -> return (map x)))
```

Edit: 
I got what I want with the following template Haskell code. Pretty sweet.

This is for declaring the composed map functions:

```
composeMap :: Int -> Q Dec
composeMap n
  | n >= 1    = funD name [cl]
  | otherwise = fail "composeMap: argument n may not be <= 0"
  where
    name = mkName $ "map" ++ show n
    composeAll = foldl1 (\fs f -> [| $fs . $f |])
    funcs = replicate n [| map |]
    composedF = composeAll funcs
    cl = clause [] (normalB composedF) []
```

This is for inlining the composed map. It is more flexible:

```
composeMap :: Int -> Q Exp
composeMap n = do
  f <- newName "f"
  maps <- composedF
  return $ LamE [(VarP f)] (AppE maps (VarE f))
  where
    composeAll = foldl1 (\fs f -> [| $fs . $f |])
    funcs = replicate n [| map |]
    composedF = composeAll funcs
```

Also, the guys who put the question on hold didn't even understand the question in the first place...

Comment: Although it is finite for every `n`, Haskell is **statically typed**. This means that the type of a function can not depend on the **value** of a parameter.

Comment: Is there any way to get around the type system in this case?

Comment: I realise it's probably not possible as we do not specify enough to the compiler: for one, the function only works for polymorphic f. Is there a way to declare a type as polymorphic? If I'm not wrong, writing a type declaration for composeMap will result in a static type for f, but that won't do.

Comment: I realise the broader question here is: how is the composition of polymorphically-typed functions handled? It seems that Haskell needs all of the information about which functions are going to be composed to come up with a sensible type inference.

Comment: Well after compile time, the type of all functions is fully known, or it does not matter. That's afaik one of the reasons one speaks of *type erasure*.

Comment: Your first definition of `composeMap` works just fine here. Your second one works fine, too, once I add a `'` to the recursive call. I'm voting to close.

Comment: You can also avoid explicit recursion with `composeMap n f = foldr (.) id (replicate n f)`.

Comment: I wouldn't say it *only* works for polymorphic functions; rather, it *works* for polymorphic functions, as long as the input and output types match, i.e., `b -> b` but not `a -> b`.

Comment: See also [`stimesMonoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#v:stimesMonoid) which is your operation when you choose `Endo a` as the `Monoid`, and [further discussion of this operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40983249/791604).

Comment: And, *both* your functions are recursive; the second one is tail-recursive because nothing is done with the return value of the recursive call except to return it.

Comment: chepner         try, for example, composeMap 3 map. Haskell, considers it, like the functions I gave in the post, as trying to implement an infinite type.

Comment: If I am interpreting your clarification correctly, then you want `composeMap 2 map` to behave like `map . map` and `composeMap 3 map` to behave like `map . map . map` and so on. Is that correct?

The type of `map . map` is `(a -> b) -> [[a]] -> [[b]]` and that of `map . map . map` is `(a -> b) -> [[[a]]] -> [[[b]]]`, i.e. you want the type of the output value of `composeMap` to depend on value of input `n` (which is always of type `Eq a, Num a => a`).  I don't think this is possible but it might be using dependent types or maybe some hack involving dynamic types.

Comment: sam             That is indeed what I want. I am open to even using templates to write the boilerplate code `(map . map . ...  . map)`

Comment: @Raskell although the thing that you want exactly is not possible, it seems like the problem you are facing is updating values in deeply nested data structures. For this there is a nice template haskell library here: https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.10/package/syb-0.7 and a good introduction to using this library is the paper 'Scrap Your Boilerplate:
A Practical Design Pattern for Generic Programming' available at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2003/01/hmap.pdf

Comment: You don't need dependent types. This is the sort of thing you can do with a type class with overlapping instances (and additionally in this case, I think you want type families), but this isn't often done because these are sort of end-of-the-road abstractions; you start to lose type inference and it's difficult to build anything useful on top of them. But this kind of thing can be useful for getting rid of boilerplate, saving programmers keystrokes or mental overhead or making an API look a little prettier on the value level and uglier in the types.

Comment: You can also model something like this with non-regular datatypes.  E.g. `data Nested f a = Pure a | Nest (Nested f (f a))` is a data type that represents the disjunction `a` or `f a` or `f (f a)` ... which would be the return type of your function.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I am missing something. Your first implementation compiles and works fine for me (ghc 8.0.2).

Your second implementation failed to compile because you forgot the `'` in the else clause. Here is my complete source file:

```
composeMap1 0 f = (\x -> x)
composeMap1 n f = (.) f (composeMap1 (n-1) f)

composeMap2' n k f g =
  if n == k then g
            else composeMap2' n (k+1) f (f . g)

composeMap2 n f = composeMap2' n 0 f (\x -> x)
```

And some tests

```
λ: :l question.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( question.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ: doubleQuote = composeMap1 2 (\x -> "'" ++ x ++ "'")
λ: doubleQuote "something"
"''something''"
λ: doubleQuote = composeMap2 2 (\x -> "'" ++ x ++ "'")
λ: doubleQuote "something"
"''something''"
λ: plusThree = composeMap1 3 (+1)
λ: plusThree 10
13
λ: plusThree = composeMap2 3 (+1)
λ: plusThree 10
13
```

Comment: As I've clarified in my post, I don't want the function to only work on f of type signature `f :: a  -> a`

Comment: @Raskell Then what type do you want your function to have?

Comment: @Carl           Maybe the type system can't handle what I want, which, really, is dependently typed.

Comment: @Will Ness What? There clearly is a `'`. I copy pasted this code from my source file (which compiled) without editing

Comment: The first `composeMap` on that line is supposed to be without `'`. It's a different function than the second `composeMap'`.

Comment: oh yes yes yes. I didn't read it through properly. sorry... :)

Comment: the OP wants `composeMap2 _n map` to work (with the actual `map` function).